# Verify SQL Server trigger is capturing all record changes

Tags: sql-server, triggers, transactions, audit

We are trying to track down record changes in a SQL Server table. Users are complaining they change a record in the morning and when they return in the afternoon, the value is changed back.

Example: column value was null. User changed to a value like 6. When they return to the record, the value might be null again or zero.

We turned on auditing in SQL Server, but I am not seeing the first edit (am) or the change back to null or zero. Yes, I am thinking user error but before I blame a user, I need to eliminate all other possibilities. I pulled a trigger event code from the web and modified it for my purposes. I put it on the specific table under triggers. It is pulling records as I expected. It keep track of what columns were changed, the old and the new values. I will admit I am not intimate with everything this code is doing so I want to ask if this code has any potential holes.

Example: would it not record an event if someone changed a column from 1 to NULL because of the NULL? `ModifiedOn` and `ModifiedBy` should be autofilled when the program saves a record. The trigger will capture the `ModifiedOn` but not consistently the `ModifiedBy`. A question was raised if `ModifiedBy` old value and new value matched (same person made both changes), would it not a record to the log the `ModifiedBy` because the values matched.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_AppointmentBase_LOG] 
ON [dbo].[AppointmentBase] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
           DECLARE @bit            INT,
                   @field          INT,
                   @maxfield       INT,
                   @char           INT,
                   @fieldname      VARCHAR(128),
                   @TableName      VARCHAR(128),
                   @PKCols         VARCHAR(1000),
                   @sql            VARCHAR(2000),
                   @UpdateDate     VARCHAR(21),
                   @UserName       VARCHAR(128),
                   @Type           CHAR(1),
                   @PKSelect       VARCHAR(1000),
                   @PKSelect2      VARCHAR(1000)


           --You will need to change @TableName to match the table to be audited.
           -- Here we made GUESTS for your example.
           SELECT @TableName = 'AppointmentBase'

           SELECT @UserName = SYSTEM_USER,
                  @UpdateDate = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 126)

           -- Action
           IF EXISTS (
                  SELECT *
                  FROM   INSERTED
              )
               IF EXISTS (
                      SELECT *
                      FROM   DELETED
                  )
                   SELECT @Type = 'U'
               ELSE
                   SELECT @Type = 'I'
           ELSE
               SELECT @Type = 'D'

           -- get list of columns
           SELECT * INTO #ins
           FROM   INSERTED

           SELECT * INTO #del
           FROM   DELETED

           -- Get primary key columns for full outer join
           SELECT @PKCols = COALESCE(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') 
                  + ' i.[' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '] = d.[' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ']'
           FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk,
                  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
           WHERE  pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
                  AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                  AND c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
                  AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

           -- Get primary key select for insert
           SELECT @PKSelect = COALESCE(@PKSelect + '+', '') 
                  + '''<[' + COLUMN_NAME 
                  + ']=''+convert(varchar(100),
           coalesce(i.[' + COLUMN_NAME + '],d.[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']))+''>''',
                @PKSelect2 = COALESCE(@PKSelect2 + '+', '') 
                  + '+convert(varchar(100), coalesce(i.[' + COLUMN_NAME + '],d.[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']))'
           FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk,
                  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
           WHERE  pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
                  AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                  AND c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
                  AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

           IF @PKCols IS NULL
           BEGIN
               RAISERROR('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)

               RETURN
           END

           SELECT @field = 0,
                  -- @maxfield = MAX(COLUMN_NAME) 
                  @maxfield = -- FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName


                  MAX(
                      COLUMNPROPERTY(
                          OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TableName),
                          COLUMN_NAME,
                          'ColumnID'
                      )
                  )
           FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE  TABLE_NAME = @TableName

           WHILE @field < @maxfield
           BEGIN
               SELECT @field = MIN(
                          COLUMNPROPERTY(
                              OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TableName),
                              COLUMN_NAME,
                              'ColumnID'
                          )
                      )
               FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
               WHERE  TABLE_NAME = @TableName
                      AND COLUMNPROPERTY(
                              OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TableName),
                              COLUMN_NAME,
                              'ColumnID'
                          ) > @field

               SELECT @bit = (@field - 1)% 8 + 1
               SELECT @bit = POWER(2, @bit - 1)
               SELECT @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1

               IF SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(), @char, 1) & @bit > 0
                  OR @Type IN ('I', 'D')
               BEGIN
                   SELECT @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME
                   FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                   WHERE  TABLE_NAME = @TableName
                          AND COLUMNPROPERTY(
                                  OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TableName),
                                  COLUMN_NAME,
                                  'ColumnID'
                              ) = @field

                   SELECT @sql = 
                          '
           insert into AppointmentBase_Log2 ( Type, 
           TableName, 
           PK, 
           FieldName, 
           OldValue, 
           NewValue, 
           UpdateDate, 
           UserName)
           select ''' + @Type + ''',''' 
                          + @TableName + ''',' + @PKSelect2
                          + ',''' + @fieldname + ''''
                          + ',convert(varchar(1000),d.' + @fieldname + ')'
                          + ',convert(varchar(1000),i.' + @fieldname + ')'
                          + ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
                          + ',''' + @UserName + ''''
                          + ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
                          + @PKCols
                          + ' where i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname 
                          + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.'
                          + @fieldname
                          + ' is not null)' 
                          + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' 
                          + @fieldname
                          + ' is null)' 



                   EXEC (@sql)
               END
           END
```

Users and managers are thinking I am not finding all the changes to the table with my code. Basically because I can not prove they changed the record in the first place let alone the second change. Based on my limited knowledge of the process above, I am not confident enough to say they are wrong.

Is there a transaction that could update a record in the table that this code could miss? Say a scheduled maintenance task that might not trigger the "U","D" or "I" types this uses. Or maybe a batch injection from an outside source?

Or, do you think I'm good with the above and should look at the user or GUI interface as not completing the transaction.

Comment: If SQL Server 2016 - then enabling system versioning is quickest way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Audit, or Trace is more appropriate than running a trigger. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior on demand, or is it intermittent and unpredictable?

Comment: As an idea, how about adding a log to your application, to capture "Submit" changes events. This way if "Submit" event is not there, user never saved changes.

Comment: Trigger analysis: 1. `ModifiedBy` - is the user that caused the trigger to fire. Note that as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/system-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 this user may not be the same as the user logged in. 2. Unless the batch disables triggers before running, this trigger should pick up changes.

Comment: RE: "We turned on auditing in SQL but I am not seeing the first edit (am) or the change back to null or zero." - do you have any logic that validates / processes input before saving, that can silently reject/fail? could it be expired user sessions (assuming web app)? Otherwise user error.

Comment: Dale: thanks for the edit

Comment: Lukasz: I should have stated we are on SQL 2012.

Comment: David: I did initiate audit first. I programmed a trigger as a double check to the audit.

Comment: Brian: I am not able to reproduce. Sporadic at best.

Comment: Alex: like your logic. Interface is third party and I don't have access to source code or can not edit it. I wish but no. I will review your link. Thx for your insight.